# Is there a log(n) algorithm for changing a lines list to a point list?

Tags: algorithm, graph

i have a list of lines represented in (pointA, pointB) formatted which is not sorted yet, like: (A, B),(C, D), (B, F), (F,C）
so far i wanna change it to a point list as: A, B, F, C, D, A
by the way, all point in lines can be retrieved.
Tks

Comment: Probably not. If you want to look at all the lines to do a thing with the points, you're looking at an _O(N)_ minimum.

Comment: so how about nlog(n)?

Comment: With a hashmap that has a O(1) amortised average time complexity for insertion and lookup, you can do it in O(n) in a trivial way.

Answer (score 1):

> With a hashmap that has a O(1) amortised average time complexity for insertion and lookup, you can do it in O(n) in a trivial way.

that's exactly what i need!
suppose i have seven line: （A, B), (A, C), (D, B), (D, E), (F, G), (F, E), (G, H), (C, H) and i convert it to A-》B-》D-》E-》F—》G-》H-》C
using hash can solve the problem quickly:

```
def point_to_hash(point):
    return str(point[0]) +','+ str(point[1])
left_hash = point_to_hash(convex_hull_lines[0][0])
points_dict = {left_hash: convex_hull_lines[0][1]}
right_hashes = [point_to_hash(convex_hull_lines[0][1])]
for line in convex_hull_lines[1:]:
    if point_to_hash(line[0]) in points_dict.keys() or point_to_hash(line[1]) in right_hashes:
        points_dict[point_to_hash(line[1])] = line[0]
        right_hashes.append(point_to_hash(line[0]))
    else:
        points_dict[point_to_hash(line[0])] = line[1]
        right_hashes.append(point_to_hash(line[1]))

convex_hull_points = [convex_hull_lines[0][0], convex_hull_lines[0][1]]
point_hash = point_to_hash(convex_hull_points[1])
step = 1
step_count = len(points_dict)
while step < step_count:
    next_point = points_dict[point_hash]
    convex_hull_points.append(next_point)
    point_hash = point_to_hash(next_point)
    step += 1
```

Comment: If you have found the answer to you question, you may consider [accepting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).